# Random fill colors in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have been using nvd3 for a long time. In nvd3 we have an option to specify automatic graph fill colors.

```
chart.barColor()
```

> How can I fill random colors in Chart.js graphs without defining each
>   color in datasets?

**I don't want to use JavaScript function to generate and get random colors from it. I need something similar to nvd3 `barColor()`**

If there is a possible way, then please help me out.

Comment: You could check my answer at [#48589545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828915/how-set-color-family-to-pie-chart-in-chart-js/48589545#48589545)

Answer (score 12):

```
        function getRandomColor() {
            var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
            var color = '#';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
                color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
            }
            return color;
                }
```

Then set:

```
fillcolor = getRandomColor()
```

Comment: OP has specifically asked that he does not want a function that randomly generates colors.

Comment: It is useful despite the question didn't asked for that.

Answer (score 5):

I am afraid there just is no in-built function in chart.js library for doing this.
And what is the harm in defining your own javascript function anyways?

The implementation would look pretty much similar to what you are looking for, except that you would have defined what `barColor()` would do yourself.

If you haven't found them already, there are a couple of great solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594478/different-color-for-each-bar-in-a-bar-chart-chartjs). (using JavaScript functions)

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. The problem I have is that I have no fixed quantity that how many bars (taking example of bar-graph) could be there in the graph. So I can not define a fixed number of colors.

Comment: In that case... what you can do is write a function which generates colors randomly starting from a selected color, not repeating the colors. I can edit my answer accordingly if you'd like :)