# Automatic colors assignment in chart.js 2.x doesn't work anymore, used to work in v. 1.x

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

Using Chart.js 1.x I could create a pie chart and get the colors automatically assigned:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.1.1/Chart.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var data = [{"label":"Conservative","value":"5"},{"label":"Democratic","value":"6"}];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
</script>
</body>
```

if I do the same with v 2.x

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
<body>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");{"label":"Democratic","value":"6"}];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'pie',
    data: {
        labels: ["Conservative", "Democratic"],
        datasets: [{
            data: [5, 15],
        }]
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

the whole Pie is displayed in Grey unless I specify the colors manually; am I missing something? The only related question I've found is this one: [Random fill colors in Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243892/random-fill-colors-in-chart-js) however, as explained above, it perfectly worked on 1.x so it seems strange to me it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I believe that creation of color schemes is a whole science of its own. It makes sense to me that something like that has been left out of Chart.js, since there are more critical goals to pursue.

All colors used in chart examples in the [docs](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) are defined explicitly. And [this two-month-old issue](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3130) features a categorical response from a Chart.js member that default colors are not available in Chart.js 2.

So, you have three choices.

- The first choice is to make some colors yourself. I guess you would not have asked the question, had you been into something like that (I know that the results would be horrible, if *I* did something like that).
- The second choice is to look for color schemes and color scheme generators online and pick some color schemes that please you.
- The third and interesting choice is to look for a JavaScript library that can produce color schemes at will.

There are a couple of alternative choices. A nice one, which is available under very permissive licensing, is the [Colour Palette Generator](http://google.github.io/palette.js/). You may see it in action along Chart.js 2 [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1xnche4v/1/). The sample is also available below:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myData = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: myData,
      backgroundColor: palette('tol', myData.length).map(function(hex) {
        return '#' + hex;
      })
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.3.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/palette.js/master/palette.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

How to use the library is described [here](https://github.com/google/palette.js). In short, you may create a 10-color palette from a specific color scheme using the following:

```
var seq = palette('tol-sq', 10);
```

The result is an array of hex strings (e.g. "eee8d5"). In order to use it where Chart.js is expecting colors, you may use `map` to prepend "#" to each string, like in the example above.

Comment: Removing the very simple default palette sounds illogical to me (I saw the related code in v1 and it was very simple) but that was the choice and your solution works very well, thanks!

Comment: @Eugenio While moving from one version to another one, functionality can disappear. But the charts and plugins work really well, so an external palette is not much of a nuisance. :)

Comment: I was looking for this because I has about 50 labels and I did not want to define 50 colors. This solution was working fine, however I had to change the first argument of `palette` to `tol-dv` since `tol` only supports 12 colors.

Comment: The example script doesn't work anymore, it seems that https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aWapBE.jsis not working. One has to include https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/palette.js/master/palette.js

Comment: When adding this script you get a cross origin error stopping it working (in latest Chrome version at least). The only way I found to get around it was to visit the palette.js url and copy and paste the code into a local js file. Works well though and does just what I wanted.

Answer (score 22):

I would actually recommend [ChartsJS-Plugin-ColorSchemes](https://nagix.github.io/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/). Simply importing it after chartjs will be enough for you to have automatic coloring but adding options will allow you to make custom palettes, for example.

```
...

  options: {

    plugins: {

      colorschemes: {

        scheme: 'tableau.Tableau20'

      }

    }

  }
```

Comment: This option is good but only seems to work for multiple datasets. If you have one dataset with multiple bars/columns/lines then all are the same colour. However the answer above by @Zeke Egherman colours these bars different colours so is more flexible. This does work fine for multiple datasets though plus colour choices seem nicer.

Comment: See this open issue: "One Dataset with multiple columns/rows are all same colour #11" (https://github.com/nagix/chartjs-plugin-colorschemes/issues/11)

Comment: This plugin will not work with custom html legend.
When get called legendCallback method for generate your custom html legend the 'chart' object passed to the function has data.datasets bacgroundColor array undefined
`code`
data: {…}
​​
datasets: (1) […]
​​​
0: {…}
​​​​
_meta: Object { 2: {…} }
​​​​
backgroundColor: undefined
​​​​
borderColor: undefined
​​​​
borderWidth: 2
​​​​
data: Array(4) [ 1, 2, 2, … ]
​​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​​
length: 1
​​​
<prototype>: Array []
​​
labels: Array(4) 
`code`

Comment: Any idea what was the name of the color scheme used by Chart.js v1.x?

Comment: Trying to use it with ng-charts, the override option doesn't work either.

Comment: I was trying to use this plugin for charts.js 3+ and it's not compatible. It took me longer than I care to admit to figure this out; maybe I saved somebody some time.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative to add automatic color generation for `Chart.js` is to use the plugin:

[chartjs-plugin-autocolors](https://github.com/kurkle/chartjs-plugin-autocolors)

```
import autocolors from 'chartjs-plugin-autocolors';

Chart.register(autocolors);

const chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  // ...
  options: {
    plugins: {
      autocolors: {
        mode: 'data'
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Note: This plugin requires Chart.js 3.0 or later

Comment: Great recommendation. I created a [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-xzm0sx) to display the result, compared to another great solution ("Golden Angle") in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129594/3002584).

Answer (score 0):

daynamic chart by random color

when data and label is daynamic

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'pie',
  data: {
    labels: label,
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: data,
      backgroundColor: getRandomColor(data.length)
      })
    }]
  }
});
function getRandomColor(count) {
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
   ar color = '#';
      for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
          color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      colors.push(color);
      }
   return colors;
}
```