# How do I change the color for ng2-charts?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have added ng2-charts to my project and display 2 charts - donut & barchart. both are **displayed in gray** since I added

```
    <base-chart class="chart"
                [colors]="chartColors"
                ...
    </base-chart>
```

to the `component.template.html`, and

```
public chartColors:Array<any> =[
    {
      fillColor:'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      strokeColor:'rgba(11,255,20,1)',
      pointColor:'rgba(111,200,200,1)',
      pointStrokeColor:'#fff',
      pointHighlightFill:'#fff',
      pointHighlightStroke:'rgba(200,100,10,0.8)'
    }, ... (3x)
```

to the `component.ts`.

Are any other package imports necessary to change the color or is the setup wrong?

Chromes html inspector shows the following html output rendered:

```
ng-reflect-colors="[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You should do this like:

```
  public chartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // first color
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)'
    },
    { // second color
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
      pointBorderColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)'
    }];
```

**Gray** color is set by default, which means your color options don't work, because of wrong properties names.

Here you have an example, how colors properties are called:

[ng2-charts-github-source-code](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/blob/master/demo/src/app/components/charts/line-chart-demo.ts)

**@UPDATE:**

If there is a need to update just backgroundColor and nothing else, code below will work too.

```
public chartColors: Array<any> = [
    { // all colors in order
      backgroundColor: ['#d13537', '#b000b5', '#c0ffee', ...]
    }
]
```

Comment: @ulon In my case its displaying only first color

Comment: @ulou is there any way to change the dougnut chart color ?.

Comment: @A.Sakkeer Check this one: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-charts/issues/955

Comment: Is there a way to change the legend color? In my use case, i am having a dark theme for my web app and dont know how to set the dark theme for the ng2-chart in angular or at least change the legend text color to white. I am using angular and ng2-charts btw.

Answer (score 52):

Also you can do it in this way:

```
<base-chart class="chart"
            [colors]="chartColors"
            ...
</base-chart>
```

and

```
public chartColors: any[] = [
      { 
        backgroundColor:["#FF7360", "#6FC8CE", "#FAFFF2", "#FFFCC4", "#B9E8E0"] 
      }];
```

Comment: Two hours later and this was the answer. Nowhere else do they show to put an array to the backgroundColor property of an object within an array. I was at the end of my rope until this post!

Comment: A slight variation of this worked for me just now: `[ { backgroundColor: '#FF7360' }, { backgroundColor: '#6FC8Ce' }, ... ]`

Answer (score 5):

If you're like me using a doughnut type chart with ng2-charts' MultiDataSet, and want to change the colors, then you will need to do something like this:

```
public doughnutChartColors: Color[] = [
  {backgroundColor:["#9E120E","#FF5800","#FFB414"]},
  {backgroundColor:["#9E120E","#FF5800","#FFB414"]},
  {backgroundColor:["#9E120E","#FF5800","#FFB414"]}
];
```

colors property in chart is like:

```
<canvas baseChart
  [data]="doughnutChartData"
  [labels]="doughnutChartLabels"
  [chartType]="doughnutChartType"
  [colors]="doughnutChartColors">
</canvas>
```

Chart looks like:

[image]

And BTW.. there is a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589545/2250792) discussing accessible colors.

[My stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular9-sand) with `Doughnut Chart` demo.

Comment: Is there a way to change the legend color? In my use case, i am having a dark theme for my web app and dont know how to set the dark theme for the ng2-chart in angular or at least change the legend text color to white. I am using angular and ng2-charts btw

Comment: Updated answer with link to my stackblitz.  Read the documentation about `ThemeService`: https://valor-software.com/ng2-charts/ and see if you can get it working there.  Then share your fork.

Answer (score 3):

```
//.ts_file     

    public chartColors() {
            return [{
              backgroundColor: this.alert.severityColor,
              borderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
              pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)',
              pointBorderColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
              pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(225,10,24,0.2)'
          }]
        }


//.html_file

<div style="display: block">
          <canvas baseChart
                  [datasets]="barChartData()"
                  [options]="barChartOptions"
                  [legend]="barChartLegend"
                  [chartType]="barChartType"
                  [colors]="chartColors()"
                  (chartHover)="chartHovered($event)"
                  (chartClick)="chartClicked($event)"></canvas>
        </div>
```

I needed to change the color of the charts dynamically based on values and colors attached to alerts. I found that @uluo had a great answer. I changed it from a property of the class to a function and returned the object with the colors set to dynamic elements in my alerts. Then I used the function to bind my chart colors and it was magic. I had been stuck on this problem for a couple of hours!

Hope this helps anyone who is trying to pass in dynamic values to ng2-charts with Angular!

Answer (score 2):

Chart colours can be set via the chart data. Useful to match specific colours to specific series.

e.g. remove or ignore the [colors] attribute and for a data specification

```
<canvas style="height: 600px" baseChart
        chartType="bar"
        [datasets]="chartData"
```

set chartData

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "y": 18353021615,
        "t": 2014
      },
    ],
    "label": "Energy",
    "backgroundColor": "rgb(229,229,229)",
    "pointBackgroundColor": "rgba(229, 229, 229, 1)",
    "pointHoverBackgroundColor": "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    "borderColor": "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    "pointBorderColor": "#fff",
    "pointHoverBorderColor": "rgba(151,187,205,1)"
  },
```

Or so the following test would pass

```
expect(component.chartData[0].backgroundColor).toBe('rgba(242,200,124,1)');
```

I have a template set of default colours

```
public readonly localChartColours: Color[] = [
{
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(78,180,189)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(78, 180, 189, 1)',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)',
  borderColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)',
  pointBorderColor: '#fff',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(151,187,205,1)'
}, {
```

Set the colours when setting the data

```
const chartDataPrototype = {data: points, label: seriesLabel};
const coloursForItem = this.findColours(this.chartData.length);
Object.keys(coloursForItem).forEach(colourProperty => {
  chartDataPrototype[colourProperty] = coloursForItem[colourProperty];
});
this.chartData.push(chartDataPrototype);
```

And overwrite them on a specific basis as needed

```
this.chartData.forEach(item => {
  if (uopColours[item.label]) {
      item.backgroundColor = uopColours[item.label];
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Colors can also be set/changed within the scope of the dataset array ifself like below (for a bar chart example):

```
public barChartData: ChartData<'bar'> = {
labels: this.barChartLabels,
datasets: [
  {
    data: [5000, 5000, 5100],
    label: 'Income',
    **>>backgroundColor: ['green','green','green']<<**,
  },
  {
    data: [4100, 3500, 3950],
    label: 'Expenses',
    **>>backgroundColor: ['red','red','red']<<**,
  },
],
};
```

Hope this helps.