# chart.js pie chart background colors: is there any way to generate them randomly?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm using chart JS to draw a pie chart with some data from the database. The problem is I don't know how many elements may appear on the chart, so generating the background colors its a bit difficult.

Is there any option so chart js would randomly generate those colors?

Comment: You could check my answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828915/how-set-color-family-to-pie-chart-in-chart-js/48589545#48589545)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, chartjs does not come with this option.

I guess you have two options:

- If you know a maximum (Ex: There won't be more than 10 values), then you can make an array with 10 colors and assign the first colors to the elements you have (Ex: If you have 5 elements, assign the first 5 colors to them). You could easily randomize for example where in the array does the assignment start, to still get a different color set every time.

  > This method if good if you want to keep your colors to match a specific color theme.
- If you do not care about a color theme, I think the easiest would be to [generate the colors randomly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator-in-javascript). With this function, you can only hope to not get twice the same color (very very unlikely):

```js
function getRandomColor() {
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
    var color = '#';
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
    }
    return color;
}

console.log(getRandomColor());
```