# Populate colors on a Chart.js chart dynamically

Tags: jquery, chart.js

I have a vue application where I am using Chart.js. I am trying to dynamically populate the chart from data in a table with a row click event. I have the data displaying in the chart, but I am trying to figure out how I could get random colors into it. Any suggestions?

This is what the function looks like:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myDoughnut");
var myDoughnut = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: {
        labels: this.getAnalyticRow[0].rowNames,
        datasets: [{
            data: this.getAnalyticRow[0].rowData,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 2,
        }]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        defaultFontColor: '#ffffff',
    }
```

This is the chart:

[image: chart]

Comment: Are you asking how to set the `backgroundColor` and `borderColor` to random colors instead of `rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)`?

Comment: ya i am sending in dynamic data to the labels and data and i want to check the length of data array and put that many colors into the chart

Comment: You could check my answer at [#48589545](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828915/how-set-color-family-to-pie-chart-in-chart-js/48589545#48589545)

Answer (score 0):

If you set background color in this way you set the background color of the first 5 elements because is array of color:

```
backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.6)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.6)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.6)'
        ],
```

To resolve this you must insert just one background color but not in string array. Example:

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.6)'
```