# Random color selection on a pie chart Chart.JS

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a database, and data is taken from it on request. How to set backgroundColor: `rgb(144,204,244)` if I don't know the number of sectors in the pie chart and it depends on the DB query. In the example on the official website, backgroundColor: `rgb(144,204,244)` is set 3 times because there are 3 sectors in the pie chart, but I have a different number of sectors in the pie chart.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("doughnut").getContext("2d");
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: expirationdates,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Оплата парковочных пространств',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(144,204,244)',
      borderColor: 'rgb(144,204,244)',
      data: prices,
    }]
  },
  options: {}
});
```

[image]

How do I set the color of the sectors if I don't know the number of these sectors in the pie chart? I read the official documentation and there the color is specified for each sector separately.

Comment: Please avoid image hostings whose links may expire soon.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45489530/12511801).

Comment: Hi @BartKrakowski I didn't understand about imgur hosted images 'expiring soon'. I thought that was where we were supposed to be putting images in SO questions/answers. Is there somewhere else I should use instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How set color family to pie chart in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28828915/how-set-color-family-to-pie-chart-in-chart-js)